# Why is the text from the title of another application window incorrect?

Tags: c#, windows, process

I'm running a small tool (on Windows 7, 32 Bit) that I would like to see what document is open in another application I've tried this, which works for NotePad on Windows.

```
        var myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("NotePad");
        string title = myProcess[0].MainWindowTitle;
        MessageBox.Show(title);
```

the output is:

```
       "New Text Document - Notepad"
```

Now, if I try another application it doesn't always give me the correct title but I noticed that most microsoft applications seem to be fine - NotePad, WordPad, EXCEL etc.  It's this other software that is an issue.  It has a long title but just returns a very simple name.

Here's what I get from my application which has processName = **"FooBar"**
The actual running window has this up the top:

> **"FooBar Software Verson 1.2 - [Results]"**

and my code gives:

> **"FooBar"**

any ideas?

[EDIT} 2012-11-19
The very crux of this issue is that I was trying to get the name of the open file from the window. It now seems that the software I'm using doesn't display it there.  What I've discovered is that a program called "AutoIT3 Window Spy" can get the text I need as the text of the open file is on the window and not only in the title.  I downloaded the source (it's part of http://www.autohotkey.com/ which is open source.  It seems to rely on many of the suggestions already made but I'm not able to figure it out just yet.)  The source code that I"m looking at is c++ and is located here https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey

So I think the solution to my problem may lay elsewhere.  This one may go unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer has stated the following:

"I think the failure may be due to a discontinued property Form.Caption in VB 6.0 that was replaced with a Form.Text in. NET"

Thank you all for your valuable suggestions along the way!

Answer (score 2):

The main window title is what you see when you go in to task manager and look at the Description column, not the window title itself.

It's the title of the process, not the title of a particular window in the process.  A given process may have any number of windows open at one time.

If you need the actual window title, you have to hook user32 something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;



namespace Application
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main ( )
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = UnsafeNativeMethods.FindWindow("Notepad", null);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
        UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(hwnd, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int GetWindowText ( IntPtr hWnd, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount );
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow ( string lpClassName, string lpWindowName );
}
```

}

Comment: Can you get the window itself or is the code of my "Foobar" setting the process description?  I have access to the person who wrote it so would they be able to adjust it to work with my tool?

Comment: the actual description says something totally different. It says "for Anothe Program v 1.3"

Comment: You'd put "Foobar" in my example code where it has "Notepad" now.  That should give you a pointer to for it.

Comment: I get an empty string for my application but it works for NotePad.  The "FooBar" applicaton is old - it may not be in C#, would that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the 'title' you're seeing is some kind of owner-drawn UI element which is overriding the visual representation of the title, while the Windows APIs are likely to ignore that sort of thing.

I'd recommend examining the window with a tool like Spy++ to see if that's the case.

It's also possible that the author of the application decided to override the `WM_GETTEXT` message and is returning that instead of what's actually in the titlebar, although I'm not 100% sure if `GetWindowText()` is being called here and whether or not it sends the message explicitly or works some other way.